# Incluir Flextable en Aplicación Flexdasboard (Rmarkdown)

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, flexdasboard

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con "Flexdasboard" (Rmarkdown), y quiero usar "Flextable", pero al incluirlo en la aplicación obtengo en sieguiente error: "cannot coerce class '"flextable"' to a data.frame".
Es para dar mejor formato de presentación a los números.
Alguien sabe como lo puedo solucionar?, se lo agradecería mucho.
Saludos,
Felipe

| Estado Comprobante | Centro de Costo | Programa | mes | nuncta | area | val | nivel1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -278460 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -283220 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 4 | educacion | 16213520 | Ingreso |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -34102 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -41401 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -47657 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -67837 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -88004 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -110466 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -165130 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -184336 | Gasto |
| Válido | a | SEP | 1 | 3 | educacion | -225652 | Gasto |

dejo parte de los datos, y parte select input:
`selectInput(inputId = "Centro de Costo", label = "Centro de Costo", choices = base2022e$`Centro de Costo`)`

Gracias

Comment: Sería ideal que pudieras compartir el código que estás usando, así es más fácil tener una idea de como ayudar.

Comment: Hola @Isaac, te dejo el código: `renderTable({
base2022 %>% 
  filter(area == "educacion", nuncta == "3" | nuncta == "4", `Estado Comprobante` == "Válido",
         `Centro de Costo` == input$`Centro de Costo`) %>% 
  group_by(Programa, nivel1) %>% 
  summarise(sum(val)) %>% 
  mutate(nivel1 = if_else(nivel1 == "Ingreso", "01 Ingreso", "02 Gasto")) %>% 
  spread(key = nivel1, value = `sum(val)`, fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(`03 Resultado` = `01 Ingreso` + `02 Gasto`) %>% 
    flextable()`
}) el error es: **cannot coerce class '"flextable"' to a data.frame**

Comment: Perdón, pero es posible que puedas subir una muestra de la data, para reproducir el mismo error.

Comment: edité la pregunta inicial

Comment: Saludos desde Alemania Felipe (Isaac Bravo)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Isaac!!! Éxito por allá!!! Ojalá Vuelvas pronto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no es posible agregar flextable() como función dentro de la función renderTable(). En el caso que quieras tener una tabla interactiva, más allá del input que le asignes, creo que es mejor opción usar la librería DT. Acá te dejo un ejemplo de como sería utilizando esta librería.

````
---
title: "Ejemplo!"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
`Centro.de.Costo` <- rep(LETTERS, 1000)
x1 <- rnorm(1000) 
x2 <- rnorm(1000) 
x3 <- rnorm(1000) 
data <- data.frame(`Centro.de.Costo`, x1, x2, x3)
```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
# Seleccionar input
selectInput(inputId = "c_cost", label = "Centro de Costo", choices = unique(data$Centro.de.Costo))
```


Page 1
=====================================  

### Chart 1

```{r}
# Crear objeto reactivo
data_filtrada <- reactive({
    req(input$c_cost)
    data_filtrada <- data %>%
        filter(Centro.de.Costo == input$c_cost) 
    })
```

    
```{r}
renderDataTable(
  data_filtrada()
)
```
````

Solo tendrías que cambiar la data, y debería funcionar. En el caso que quieras agregar algún tipo de funcionalidad especial a la tabla, puedes revisa la documentación del package DT acá https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

**OUTPUT**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]